# Java - Method on new operator

Tags: java

Well, I'm not sure if I can do this but let me ask the question anyway...

I got class Budynek which constructor is like this:

```
public Budynek(int numerBudynku)
{
    this.id.nrBudynku = numerBudynku;
    this.id.nrPietra = 0;
    this.id.nrPokoju = 0;
}
```

so I am creating it like this:

```
Budynek Budynek1 = new Budynek(1);
Budynek Budynek2 = new Budynek(2);
```

Now I want to ask if there is any way to create a method that create new Budynek for me? Lets say if I use switch case, and case 1 will be "create new Budynek"

then I would like this method to do something like this

```
 e.g licznik = 1

Budynek Budynek+licznik(so it will be Budynek1) = new Budynek(licznik)
```

then just licznik = licznik + 1;

is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to declare variable names dynamically - in which case, the answer is "no".

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for :(

Comment: You can do it by Reflection.

Comment: So you probably want a collection of some description - maybe an array or a `List<Budynek>`.

Comment: @bigdestroyer: You can't *declare* variables with reflection at execution time.

Comment: What about something like a Map<String,Budynek> to map names to instances ? `map.put("Buynek"+licznik, new Budynek(licznik) )`

Comment: @bigdestroyer Can you gibe an example how to do it with reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a List and store everything there, since your are indexing anyways with `budynek+index`

```
List<Budynek> budynekList = new ArrayList<Budynek>();

budynekList.add(new Budynek(10));
budynekList.add(new Budynek(20));
budynekList.add(new Budynek(400));

budynekList.get(index); // now you have your budynek objects with the given index.
```

As in the comments already pointed out, you can't declare variables on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
enum Budynek {
    BUDYNEK_A,
    BUDYNEK_B,
    BUDYNEK_C;

    public ID id;

    private Budynek() {
        this.id.nrBudynku = 1 + ordinal();
        this.id.nrPietra = 0;
        this.id.nrPokoju = 0;
    }
}

Budynek.BUDY_A.id.nrBudynku
```

or you must go for an array:

```
Budynek[] budyneki = new Budynek[3];
...
budyneki[0].id.nrBudynku
budyneki[1].id.nrBudynku
budyneki[2].id.nrBudynku
```

Comment: Looks like list is doing job. I still can get access to methods like that:

    `List<Budynek> budynekList = new ArrayList<Budynek>();
     budynekList.add(new Budynek(licznik));
  budynekList.get(0).dodajPietro();
  budynekList.get(0).naPietrze(0).dodajPokoj();
  budynekList.get(0).opis();`

so thanks !